# parse.com | how to modify a text string?

Tags: string, class, text, parse-platform

i'm trying to modify a text string inside Parse data browser using an text field.
here how it's look in parse ( trying to change the text " change Text " ) :

[image]

i tried to use this code , but surely it's not the right method . 
with getObjectInBackgroundWithId i need to change it to something else but use the Current User(which for this example is  WMOmhmrO3 ) .

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NewChat"];
[query includeKey:@"text"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser] block:^(PFObject *object, NSError  *error) {
    object[@"text"]=_chatField; // chat field is my Text field
    [object saveInBackground];
}];
```

any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
object[@"text"]=_chatField; // chat field is my Text field
```

Should be:

```
object[@"text"]=_chatField.text;
```

After a second view, there are more problems:

```
[query includeKey:@"text"];
```

`includeKey:` is used for pointers to other PFObjects.  Because your "text" key corresponds to a string, this line is unnecessary.

Here, you're trying to query for a chat where the id matches `[PFUser currentUser]` because this is a pointer to a user object and the "objectId" field corresponds to a string, this will never work.

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser] block:// etc.
```

It should be

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"<The Id Of The Object You Want>" block:// etc.
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i forgot to put the _chatField.text :D , but still i don't understand how can i change the text in table with the right code, because clearly mine is wrong .

Comment: Did you edit your code according to all the point in Logan's answer? You need to get the correct object using an objectID, not PFUser object and you need to use the .text property of your field. If you do this, your code should work. But an NSLog statement inside your block to check if you have the correct object.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i can't get the object ID since it's different in every user, that's why i thought PFuser currentUser would work. how can i get the object ID of every different user ?